# iOS 12.0 Safari - distorted image when scrolling

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, vertical-scrolling

I have stumbled upon very strange problem with latest iOS update. From time to time, images get distorted while scrolling.
[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxpR9.png)

This problem only appears in iOS 12.0 safari. Sometimes it takes a while, scrolling up an down, to reproduce this issue.
I have tried to pinpoint elements which might be causing the issue in HTML, but so for no luck.

I have also hosted plain HTML page on AWS without any java script, and problem can be reproduced there as well:
http://ec2-52-56-231-146.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/demo/Dagligvareportalen.htm

Maybe You have some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda too late, but hey, I got the same problem so here we are :)

in the dynamic elements don't use [css filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter); that's all. 
get rid of `filter: ...` and you'll be free of that bug